# How can this intel instruction be written in ATT

Tags: x86, intel, att

```
movl DWORD[%ebp+8], %eax
```

AS assembler is not accepting this line with following error:

```
junk [%ebp+8] after expression
```

How to properly rewrite it in AT&T syntax?

Comment: http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm

Comment: I glossed over that before but it is confusing because it does not include the DWORD.

Comment: It does if you look at the very bottom regarding `suffixes`

Comment: So DWORD[ebp+8] and dword ptr[ebp+8] are equivalent?

Comment: There are a couple different variants of Intel syntaxes. There is what MASM/TASM/JWASM use where they require `ptr` but there are other intel syntaxes (like yasm, nasm) where the `ptr` isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd write it as:

```
movl %eax, 8(%ebp)
```